# How long does memory written with memset() stay in memory without calling free()?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, system, memset

On Linux.

Hi. I'm sure there are many factors involved where the OS simply garbage-dumps memory allocated with memset() without calling free(), but I was wondering if anyone has a good estimation on this? That's really all I want to know.

There is a functionality in linux called KSM that saves memory space by combining matching data. My question revolves around detecting if KSM is working or not by checking the write time of the data. I have already successfully tested this on a machine while running everything in one program. Now I want to upload to memory, close the program, then open another program and test for memory duplication.

Thanks!

-Taylor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- memset does not allocate memory, malloc does
- the memory is not freed until a free call or the process terminates
- there is no abstract machine in C, that the design principle of the language

Comment: You say "until the process terminates", does that mean once the c program finishes running the memory will be freed?

Comment: and do you know a way to keep the content in memory? I mean, I could just sleep the program.

Comment: @Tdizzle: What are you actually attempting to achieve?

Comment: As long as the process lives the memory will not be reclaimed. This is actually OS dependent but also generally true.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I am making a program that detects a malicious VM

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk about abstractions:

- A C programmer writes software for a "C abstract machine". This has nothing to do with any real hardware.
- The "C abstract machine" is converted into something (e.g. an executable file) that runs in some kind of "process" abstraction. This "process" abstraction has nothing to do with any real hardware (it uses "threads" and not real CPUs, "virtual memory" and not real RAM, "files" and not real disk space, ...).
- The OS creates the "process" abstraction on top of a machine. For KSM (where the OS is running inside a virtual machine) this "virtual machine" abstraction has nothing to do with any real hardware.

Now; let's define "abstraction" as a deliberate lie intended to shield people from reality (and let's also define "security vulnerability" as a flaw in the lie).

**To determine the relationship between "memory in the C abstraction machine" and actual physical resources (RAM chips, disk space, etc) at any point in time; you need to break through a minimum of 3 barriers deliberately designed to prevent you from knowing the relationship.**

Comment: Umm ok, could you tell me what those 4 barriers are?

Comment: @Tdizzle: D'oh - it's 3 barriers (between 4 abstractions) - will correct that. Specifically; the barrier between "C abstract machine" and "process"; between "process" and "virtual machine", and between "virtual machine" and "physical machine".

Comment: Note that KSM operates at the lowest level - it's (literally) finding pages that are the same in 2 or more virtual machines and then lying to each virtual machine (letting the OS in the virtual machine continue to think it has exclusive ownership of the page when it doesn't).

Comment: ohh k, so you're saying that all the abstraction is for security reasons? right?

Comment: @Tdizzle: Some of the reasons are for security. Others are for portability, for backwards or forwards compatibility, for managing complexity, for ease of learning and debugging, for performance, for business reasons (partitioning who funds and develop which parts of a system), or because such-and-such is the way we've always done it. Theres's not one single reason for abstraction.

Comment: @Tdizzle: The reasons for the abstractions vary - sometimes it's convenience (e.g. being able to compile the same C source code for many very different operating systems/computers, being able to send a packet without caring which exact manufacturer and model of network card there is, ...) and sometimes the reason is security; but there's almost always an intention to use the abstraction to enhance security (e.g. prevent data leaking from one VM or process or from kernel to malicious code running in another VM or process)